# React hook form validation using Zod for react-select is not working in Next.js + Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, chakra-ui, zod

*By default, 'required' error is popping up but even after selecting an option the error doesn't go away.* I am adding my codes here (apologies- skipped most of the styles to make the post shorter) -

1. Reusable Dropdown component using AsyncSelect from react-select library -

**components/RawDropdownInput.tsx**

```js
import { Box,FormControl,FormErrorMessage,FormLabel,Text} from '@chakra-ui/react'
  import { IDropdownInput } from '../../../../@types'
  import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
  import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

  const RawDropdownInput: React.FC<IDropdownInput> = ({
    inputLabel,
    error,
    name,
    value,
    variant,
    placeholder,
    type = 'text',
    register,
    mandatory = false,
    inputOptions,
    ...restProps
  }) => {
  
    const handleChange = (selectedOption: any) => {
      console.log("handleChange", selectedOption);
    }

    const { control } = useForm({});
    
  
    const customStyles = {
      option: (defaultStyles: any, state: { isSelected: any, isDisabled: any, isFocused: any }) => ({
        ...defaultStyles,
        color: state.isFocused ? '#109776' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
      }),
  
  
      control: (defaultStyles: any) => ({
        ...defaultStyles,
        backgroundColor: "none",
      }),
      singleValue: (defaultStyles: any) => ({ ...defaultStyles, color: "black" }),
    };
  
  
    const loadOptions = (
      inputValue: any,
      callback: (arg0: any) => void)  => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const filteredOptions = inputOptions!.filter((option) =>
           option.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
        );
        callback(filteredOptions);
      }, 2000);
    };
  
  
    return (
      <>
        <FormControl position="relative" isInvalid={error ? true : false}>
          {inputLabel && (
            <FormLabel position="absolute" top="-8px" left="8px" bg="white" px={2} zIndex="1" >
              <Text>
                <Text as="span">{inputLabel}</Text>
                {mandatory ? (
                  <Text as="span" color="red" ml="1">
                    *
                  </Text>
                ) : null}
              </Text>
            </FormLabel>
          )}
 


        <Controller
            name={"name"}
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: 'This Field is required' }}
            render={({ field }) => <AsyncSelect
            {...field} 
            id={name}
            name={name}
            placeholder = "Select the option"
            onChange={handleChange}
            loadOptions={loadOptions}
            defaultOptions
            styles={{
              menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 }), 
              ...customStyles, 
            }} 
            components={{
              IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
            }}
          />}
          {...restProps}
        />
          
          <FormErrorMessage>{error}</FormErrorMessage>
        </FormControl>
      </>
    )
  }
  
  
  export default RawDropdownInput
```

**components/DropdownInput.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import AppGenericDropdown from './RawDropdownInput'
import { IDropdownInput } from '../../../../@types'
import useAppForm from '@/hooks/useAppForm'


const DropdownInput: React.FC<IDropdownInput> = (props) => {
  const { errors, register } = useAppForm();

  let error = errors[props?.name!]?.message;

  if (props?.name?.includes('.')) {
    const formControls = props?.name?.split('.');
    error = errors?.[formControls[0]]?.[formControls[1]]?.message;
  }


  return <AppGenericDropdown error={error} register={register} {...props} />
}

export default DropdownInput
```

2. Reusable Form component -

**components/AppForm.tsx**

```js
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import React, { createContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import * as z from 'zod'

interface IProps {
  onSubmit: (_data: any) => void
  children: React.ReactNode | Function
  schema: z.ZodObject<any>
  defaultValues?: any
}

interface IInitialState {
  errors: any
  register: any
  setValue: Function
  reset?: Function
  control: any
}

export const AppFormContext = createContext<IInitialState>({
  errors: {}, register: '', setValue: () => {}, control: {}
})

const AppForm: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  children,onSubmit,schema,defaultValues,
}) => {
  const {
    register,getValues,setValue,handleSubmit,reset,watch,control,formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    reset(defaultValues)
  }, [JSON.stringify(defaultValues)])

  return (
    <AppFormContext.Provider value={{ errors, control, register, setValue, reset }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {typeof children === 'function'
          ? children({ errors,control, reset, register, getValues, watch, setValue })
          : children}
      </form>
    </AppFormContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AppForm
```

3. Here is the implementations of those components -

**form.tsx**

```js
import AppForm from '@/components/shared/AppForm/AppForm'
import DropdownInput from '@/components/shared/input/DropdownInput'
import { Container } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { z } from 'zod'

export const whichChildOfParents = [
  { label: '1st', value: '1st' },
  { label: '2nd', value: '2nd' },
]

const nameSchema = z.object({
  dropdown: z.string().nonempty("This field is required")
})

const MyForm = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log('data: ', data)
  }
  return (
    <Container mt={2}>
      <AppForm schema={nameSchema} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <>
          <DropdownInput
            name='dropdown'
            inputLabel="Which child of the parents?"
            mandatory={true}
            inputOptions={whichChildOfParents}
          />

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </>

      </AppForm>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default MyForm
```